# Can't get post thumbnail to display in foreach loop

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, php, popular-posts

I've been trying to get the post thumbnail to display in the foreach loop for a few hours now and I can't figure out how to make it work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
          <div id="home-posts" class="col-sm-3" role="complementary">

          <div class="recent-post-sidebar">

          <h3>Popular Posts</h3>

         <?php 
                $popular_post_object = new WDS_JetPack_Popular_Posts( array( 
                            'count' => 5, 
                            'days' => 200, 
                            'transient_affix' => '_mypp')) ;?>

          <?php $popular_post_results = $popular_post_object->get_posts();?>

          <?php if ( !empty( $popular_post_results ) ) { 

    foreach( $popular_post_results as $popular_post ) {

        echo '<a href="' . $popular_post['permalink'] . '">';
        echo '<div class="post one">';
        echo '<div class="post overlay"></div>';
        echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($popular_post->ID, 'wpbs-featured-full');
        echo'<h5>'. $popular_post['title'] .'</h5>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';

    }
}?>

       </div>

       </div>
```

The original source of the code is [WebDevStudios](https://webdevstudios.com/2014/10/02/displaying-your-popular-posts-using-jetpack/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation that you have linked to, you would see that the post ID is stored in the array key `post_id` and not `ID`.

You should then change

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($popular_post->ID, 'wpbs-featured-full');
```

to

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($popular_post['post_id'], 'wpbs-featured-full');
```

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy :-)